# NullPointException in ListView when getting button

Tags: java, android

I am having a weird problem and can't seem to find whats causing it. Every view component in my ArrayAdapter is being located in the getView method except my button which is causes a NullPointerException.

Adapter:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>{

private Context context;
private int resource;
private List<Item> list;

public ItemAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> list) 
{
    super(context, resource, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.list = list;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resource, parent,false);

    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
    ImageView itemImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemImg);
    Button addToCart = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    final Item item = list.get(position);
    name.setText(item.getName());

    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(itemImg, item.getPicture());
    addToCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

}
```

Fragment with listview

```
    @InjectView(R.id.itemList)   private ListView listView;
@Inject private ItemDao dao;

private ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    dao.open();
    List<Item> items = dao.findAll();
    dao.close();

    adapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_product_item, items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

list_product_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/itemImg"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemStoreName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now the call to convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1) returns a null instance. What is the cause of this and how can I fix it.

Comment: also post the logcat results please,

Answer (score 0):

do you have right the name of the layout?

adapter = new GroceryItemAdapter(getActivity(), **R.layout.list_textview**, items);

vs.

list_product_item

(I am assuming this is the file name for **R.layout.list_product_item**)

Comment: crop is pasted the wrong fragment. Sorry about that going to update my post

Comment: Updated, please review.

Comment: Please can you paste the logcat output?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the layout inflater using the from method try initializing the inflater in the constructor..

```
  mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

in the **getView**

```
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(your layout, null);
```